# Combination Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I'm trying to create a combination matrix of products in PANDAS. For example, "how many client have both product a and product b". The data  is currently structured this way:

[image]

what I want to see is this:

[image]

for example, 66% of the clients who buy product A also buy product B.

THANKS!!!

Comment: please don't paste images of code or data: it makes it harder for us to replicate your setup and answer your question...

Comment: also, in your example, is the expected output supposed to correspond to the input you presented? In that case, I don't understand: first, such a matrix should be symmetric. Second, how can anyone (25%) have bought product B and C when nobody bought B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have set your dataframe such that `client` is the index and you have only "product" columns left, then:

```
z = df.T @ df / df.sum()
```

Example:

```
# 1. setup (I can't paste an image in and get a dataframe out...)
n = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(n, 3)),
    index=np.random.randint(1000, 100000, size=n),
    columns=[f'product{k}' for k in 'ABC']).rename_axis('client')

print(df)
# out:
        productA  productB  productC
client                              
11348          1         1         0
69764          0         1         1
54055          0         1         0
18410          0         0         1
8826           1         0         0
```

Then:

```
# 2. calc
z = df.T @ df / df.sum()

print(z)
# out:
          productA  productB  productC
productA       1.0  0.333333       0.0
productB       0.5  1.000000       0.5
productC       0.0  0.333333       1.0
```

Note also that the behavior when the sum for a column is zero, you'll get corresponding `NaN` in the result:

```
# for df =
        productA  productB  productC
client                              
25721          0         0         0
56693          0         0         0
11888          1         0         0
57777          1         0         0
19599          0         1         0

# we get z =
          productA  productB  productC
productA       1.0       0.0       NaN
productB       0.0       1.0       NaN
productC       0.0       0.0       NaN
```